# Ruby: How do I capture part of a string with regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have

```
  file_ext = attach.document_file_name.capture(/\.[^.]*$/)
```

but i guess there is no method capture.

I'm trying to get the file extension from a string. I don't yet have the file.

Comment: There's no need to start all of your questions with "Ruby on Rails" or "Regex" - that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
file_ext = attach.document_file_name[/\.[^.]*$/]
```

Comment: Note that it returns `nil` if no extension is found. If you prefer an empty string, append a to_s at the end of line.

Answer (score 10):

There is also the built-in ruby function [File.extname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.4/classes/File.html#M000029):

```
file_ext = File.extname(attach.document_file_name)
```

*(with the difference that* `File.extname('hello.')` *returns* `''`, *whereas your regex would return* `'.'`*)*

Comment: +1 Why mess with regular expressions when there is a function that does exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can do RegEx match in ruby like so:

```
file_ext = (/\.[^.]*$/.match(attach.document_file_name.to_s)).to_s
```

Fore more information please check http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an regexp to do this, you can simply do:

```
irb(main):040:0> "foo.txt"[/\w*.(\w*)/,1]
=> "txt"
```